# proof of this theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$$\boxed{\mathbf{Theorem:}\textit{ If }\alpha \textit{ is a root of }Q(x)\textit{ then }(x-\alpha)\textit{ divides }Q(x).}$$

What is the proof of this theorem? I've tried to do euclidean division of Q(x) by x-α  but it doesn't work... :/

Thanks!

Comment: see this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem

Comment: Hint: What is remainder of division if it is divsible? and what is value of polynomial at root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we divide $Q(x)$ by $(x-a)$, and get the remainder $r$:

$$
Q(x)=(x-a)P(x)+r
$$

obviously, $r$ is a constant since $(x-a)$ is a polynomial of order 1.

Let $x=a$ in the above equation, we get:

$$r=0$$

Comment: Elegant yet effective,as all math should be

Comment: In fact, Ruffini's rule tells us that $Q(x)=Q(a)+(x-a)P(x)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write $Q(x) = Q(x) - Q(a) = a(n)(x^n - a^n) + a(n-1)(x^{n-1} - a^{n-1}) + \cdot$
Factor out each $x^n - a^n = (x - a)P(x)$.

Comment: Latex please I do'n't understand

Comment: This is the essence of the proof of Ruffini's rule.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of the form $k(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)\cdots(x-a_n)$ with a root $\alpha \not \in \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\cdots,a_n\}$ and $k\ne0$

Now $Q(\alpha) = k(\alpha-a_1)(\alpha-a_2)(\alpha-a_3)(\alpha-a_4)\cdots(\alpha-a_n)$. All the factors in this product are non zero. Obviously $k\prod_{i=1}^n\alpha-a_i$ cannot be zero, contradicting our assumption that $\alpha$ is a root.

Thus $\alpha \in \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\cdots,a_n\}$